# How to Synchronize thousands of android devices to do same thing

Tags: android, synchronization

Firstly, i have no error, no written codes. Only i want to do is brainstorming about the article.

I want to make an app, which forces the thousands of users to do same thing at the same time and also with the same start time. For example, playing a song with the same start time. I think, i can use **socket technologies** to communicate this devices with the server. Maybe i can use **Tcp ip communication** based on the server clock.

It is not an easy task i know but is not impossible. The first problem is network delay on communication. Also time synchronization of android device and server is another problem. Then time synchronization of all android devices is also another problem. After, client side delay of starting the wanted operation with respect to android devices capability and quality of processor is also another problem. I have many problems to solve.

If you think "   ...." is another problem, please told me. If you suggest firstly you should investigate **this**, please told me. In brief, please told me everything about that article.

Comment: To make all devices work exactly at the same time (exact moment in space) through network communications -> **Its practically not possible**. Just wonder, where do you require such implementation? :)

Comment: Why **Its practically not possible**? For example, I can use it on football matches for making cheers loudly, why not? :)

Comment: Communicating with thousands of devices over such crowded network (wifi/cellular) will definitely add delay to execute your desired operation.

Comment: Yes, i know. You think i can not solve this time problem? From server i receive the message "OperationTime : 6:00pm, CurrentTime : 5:55pm". If i can calculate the delay of receiving this message from server, i could manage it, i think.

Comment: Yes, you may solve the problem, but network delays may vary - like I said, especially in crowded networks.

Comment: Hmm, i will note what you said. I want to know if another thing comes to your mind :)

Comment: I know this is old but... there are two possible ways to try it (neither of which will be reliable): send a message, or use a time.  If you send a message, as mentioned there could be delays. If you use a time (let's say instruct the device to do something at 18:00 UTC), the devices' clocks will not be perfectly synchronized, so that won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this article. I used Network Time Protocol for taking the real time. My start point is [that project](https://github.com/duytuan001/NTP_Android/tree/master/NTPTimeSync)